# google analytics on android doesn't work

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use a Transaction/purchase event, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Also, I'm using Eclipse, and as far as I understand the latest sdk(v4) doesn't support it.. All I need though is just sending the purchase price that was made.

```
private static Tracker getTracker(){
        return GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(App.getContext()).getTracker(TRACKING_ID);
    }

HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder builder= new HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder();
        builder.set( "TransactionId", timeString );
        builder.set( "Revenue", Double.toString( orderSum ) );
        builder.set( "Affiliation", "Android" );
        builder.set( "Shipping", "0" );
        builder.set( "Tax", "0" );
        getTracker().set( "&cu", "USD" ); 
        getTracker().send( builder.build() );

        HitBuilders.ItemBuilder itemBuilder= new HitBuilders.ItemBuilder();
        itemBuilder.set( "TransactionId", timeString );
        itemBuilder.set( "Name", Double.toString( orderSum ) );
        itemBuilder.set( "SKU", "Android" );
        itemBuilder.set( "Price", Double.toString( orderSum ) );
        itemBuilder.set( "Quantity", "1" );
        getTracker().set( "&cu", "USD" ); 
        getTracker().send( builder.build() );

    }
```

Comment: Did you generated  the configuration file for the same? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: No.. but I'm using Eclipse, which forces me to stick to older sdk of google analytics. Do I still have to generate the config file?
I remember I once used google analytics without any config files.

thanks/

Comment: No problem BVtp. Ok, its not required, because i can see you are giving tracker id in the code itself. Have added required receivers and services in the manifest? Please follow this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-analytics-v4-example/

Comment: I have all that, I already have a couple events that do work. But this purchase event just doesn't appear at all for some reason..